# Make asynchronous calls synchronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I used to build web apps in PHP, thus the habit to do things synchronously.

I'm currently trying to build a web scraper. The way it works is

1. Grab list of proxies
2. Check if proxies are working
3. Scrape web content using proxies.

However, I've realized that most of the calls are synchronous and I had a hard time understanding async module in nodejs.

This is the main method.

```
var proxyChecker = require('proxy-checker');
var request = require('request');
var forEach = require('async-foreach').forEach;
var async = require('async');

var proxiesJar = [];
var goodProxies = [];
var proxyCount = 0;    
parseProxiesList(function(error) {
        async.each(proxiesJar, checker, function(err, result) {
            console.log('Result:' + err);
        });
    });
```

Getting proxy list

```
function parseProxiesList(callback) {
    console.log("parseProxiesList");
    request('http://hidden.com', function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error [1]");
            return callback(error);
        }
        console.log("Got proxies list");
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            proxies = body.split(/\r?\n/);
            var shouldBreak = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < proxies.length; i++) {
                if (/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\:[0-9]{1,5}/.test(proxies[i])) {
                    p = proxies[i].split(' ');
                    var elts = p[0].split(':');
                    var host = elts[0];
                    var port = elts[1];
                    proxiesJar.push(host + ":" + port);
                }
            }
            callback(null, 1);
        }
    });
}
```

After getting the proxy list, it checks if the proxy is working.

```
var checker = function(proxy, callback) {
    var p = proxy.split(':');
    var host = p[0];
    var port = p[1];
    console.log('[Checking] ' + host + ':' + port);
    proxyChecker.checkProxy(host, port, {url: 'http://google.com',regex: /Google/}, function(host, port, ok, statusCode, err) {

        if(!ok) {
            console.log("Proxy don't work: " + host + ":" + port);
            return callback(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Working proxy: " + host + ":" + port);
            goodProxies.push(host + ":" + port);
            return callback(null, host + ":" + port);
        }
    });
};
```

The logs, however, turns out to be

```
[Checking] 1.1.1.1:80
[Checking] 2.2.2.2:80
.
.
.
Working proxy: 1.1.1.1:80
Working proxy: 2.2.2.2:80
```

instead of

```
[Checking] 1.1.1.1:80
Working proxy: 1.1.1.1:80

[Checking] 2.2.2.2:80
Working proxy: 2.2.2.2:80
```

Comment: i think you're title is backwards. your code is already asynchronous. heck the whole question has it mixxd up.

Comment: @KevinB Sorry, fixed. Was getting really confused about both terms.

Comment: generally it's not possible to make asynchronous code synchronous unless there's a separate method that executes synchronously, for example, readFile vs readFileSync. You can however cause the code to execute in series, which is what peter's answer below does.

Answer (score 1):

async.each executes iterators for each item in parallel.

Use [async.eachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#synchronous-iteration-functions) for synchronous calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can try promises, creating a promise to get a proxy and then a execute a promise to check it.

You can find more on promises over [here](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/promises-in-node-js-with-q-an-alternative-to-callbacks/)

Example:

```
function parseProxiesList() {
    var deferred = Q.defer()
    console.log("parseProxiesList");
    request('http://hidden.com', function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error [1]");
            deferred.reject(error);
        }
        console.log("Got proxies list");
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            proxies = body.split(/\r?\n/);
            var shouldBreak = false;

            for (var i = 0; i < proxies.length; i++) {
                if (/[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\:[0-9]{1,5}/.test(proxies[i])) {
                    p = proxies[i].split(' ');
                    var elts = p[0].split(':');
                    var host = elts[0];
                    var port = elts[1];
                    proxiesJar.push(host + ":" + port);
                }
            }
            deffered.resolve(proxiesJar);
        }
        return deffered.promise;
    });
}
```

This way you have created a promise to get a proxy list. Similarly you can do it for checking proxy.